# don't match if string contains a whitespace javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out the regex pattern for not matching strings if the string contains whitespace. For example

"The " should not match "The"

"House " should not match "House"

Comment: What's your exact goal and what did you try?
This might help you: https://regex101.com/r/CpR8xb/1

Comment: So why use a regular expression? `if(a==b){}`

Comment: @wikunia my goal is to search for specific books in my search engine, so for example if I typed "House" it should autosuggest something like "Housemate", but if I typed "House "(with a space after house), it should autosuggest something like: "House of Cards"

Comment: the `house ` regexp doesn't match "house" ; you must have something stripping your input strings before constructing the regexp. Spaces have no special meaning in regexp and must be matched as any other character : if I used the `houseX` regexp, I wouldn't expect it to match "house".

Comment: @JAYNATHAN do you work with a database backend like mysql? Then `like` might be your friend. Otherwise more code would be reasonable. It's possible to just check if a `indexOf` works returns `>=0`

Comment: the aim is that "house<space> " should not match "house"

Comment: right now i have an if statement, which is very confusing:

Comment: `'bookTitle'.indexOf('string') >= 0` is that you want ... no need REGEX

Comment: if ((dsL.startsWith(term) && (!dsL.startsWith(term + ' ')))|| (dslnp.startsWith(term) && !dslnp.startsWith(term + ' '))) {

Comment: Why did you even mention regex in your title and added it as a tag? Where do you see a regular expression here? This is a pure javascript problem, and you should disclose your javascript code (and more than the non-formatted comment above)

Comment: `"house "` should not match `"house"` so you have code somewhere that is doing a `trim()`.

Comment: @Aaron I thought that this can be achieved using regex, instead of using if statements

Comment: `House` should match `HouseOfCards` but not `House of Cards`. Basically neglect the match if the next character of match is a whitespace? You should actually mention you actual requirement. Sounds like [`XY` problem](http://xyproblem.info)!

Comment: @sabithpocker basic problem is that when i type "house<space>" it should not match "house"

Comment: Your problem is that your implementation is incorrect. If you were to correctly implement your algorithm with regex you sure would have solved your problem, but maybe could you not bother with regular expressions and instead fix your problem with pure javascript? The `if` statement you posted indeed is confusing to say the best. You should remove the useless `!dsL.startsWith(term + ' ')` checks and make sure you haven't switched the two variables.

Comment: @Aaron the if statements work, but I wanted a simpler and cleaner way of doing it

Comment: Regex would definitely be a more complex and dirtier way to do it.

Comment: You need to show your code and how you are getting the string and running the comparison check. That will show us why you have a trim method...

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the search string is inside any of the books in your list.

```
var matches = function(search, books) {
  return books.filter(function(book) {
    return book.indexOf(search) !== -1
  })
}
```

I do not think you need regex in this case.

See that 'house ' is not inside 'house' but is inside 'house of'

Comment: I would advise against the use of regex, unless the user know how to use them. For example an user searching "mr.hide" would match "mrahide", searching "a* book" would match "aaa book" and "is this real?" would match "is this rea". If this makes no sense to you, imagine your poor users...

Comment: Yeah, That regex example was pretty broke. I have removed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) that fits well to your requirement, use the polyfill for older/unsupported browsers.

```js
var strings = ["HouseArrest", "House arrest", "HouseOfCards", "House of cards"];

function search(val){
   var res = strings.filter(i=>i.startsWith(val));
   console.clear();
   console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  }
```

```html
<input onkeyup="search(this.value)" type="text"/>
```